# Wordpress blog : Import content

Tags: database, wordpress, import, blogs, adsense

I am running a website using PHP/MySQL. Now I want to allow Blogs using wordpress in my website so I can use Google Adsense along with blog content. I have installed Wordpress on my site, using tools provided by host service provider.

Now is there anyway I can import selective-content from MySQL database to these wordpress blogs? If so, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **maybe**.

It all depends on how the content in your existing MySQL database was structured.  If the old content was created by a content management system, see if it has a built-in exporter.  WordPress [has plug-ins that can import](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/importer) from a variety of commonly-used CMS platforms already.  Check to see if yours is supported.

Unfortunately, if your content was just kind of "there" in the database without a CMS or any kind of standard (non-custom) structure, then this won't really work.  My recommendation would be to use phpMyAdmin to export your content, then use a text editor to cut out the portions you want to keep and manually create new blog posts within WordPress.  This process will be very time consuming but can be optimized if you want to build a custom importer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can import/export your contents from/to other site respectively using following ways

> 1. Using Plugins like duplicator etc
> 2. Using the existing WordPress tools availabe in the Dashboard/Admin section like **Import & Export**

There may be other different methods also available on the internet.